# Django contact form doesnt submit

Tags: django, django-forms, form-submit, contact-form

I am trying to set up a contact form. I have implemented the Django-crispy-forms and now my form is not submitted (I don't have any errors).

I've added action="" to my form in my template without any success.

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter your name or username')
    email = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, 'cols': 40}), help_text='Example: I forgot my password!')
```

views.py

```
def contact_us(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            sender_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            sender_email = form.cleaned_data['email']

            message = "From {0}:\n\n{1}".format(sender_name, form.cleaned_data['message'])
            send_mail('PLM_Tool contact', message, sender_email, ['myadress@gmail.com'])
            return redirect('home:index')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render(request, 'accounts/contact.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [path('contact/', views.contact_us, name='contact'),]
```

contact.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block main %}
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.message|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
<a href="{% url 'home:index' %}" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
<br><br>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: try putting `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>` inside the `<form> ... (here)</form>` . I've not used django-cripsy-forms yet, so can't say much about this, but looking at the documentation of crispy forms, it looks ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem, and do not give action to form
crispy forms create the field not the button.

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.message|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
    </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
</form>
```

just add the button inside the form